# Run scrapy as normal python files

Tags: python, scrapy

After a lot of search for this topic of how to run scrapy python file as normal python files I have tried the commented lines

```
import scrapy
#from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class HamburgSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hamburg'
    #allowed_domains = ['https://www.hamburg.de']
    start_urls = ['https://www.hamburg.de/branchenbuch/hamburg/10239785/n0/']
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8-sig'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        items = response.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'item')]")
        for item in items:
            business_name = item.xpath(".//h3[@class='h3rb']/text()").get()
            address1 = item.xpath(".//div[@class='address']/p[@class='extra post']/text()[1]").get()
            address2 = item.xpath(".//div[@class='address']/p[@class='extra post']/text()[2]").get()
            phone = item.xpath(".//div[@class='address']/span[@class='extra phone']/text()").get()

            yield {
                'Business Name': business_name,
                'Address1': address1,
                'Address2': address2,
                'Phone Number': phone
            }

#process = CrawlerProcess()
#process.crawl(HamburgSpider)
#process.start()
```

Without the commented lines I ususally run the code using this line

```
scrapy runspider HamburgSpider.py -o output.csv
```

Now I have the code like that

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class HamburgSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hamburg'
    #allowed_domains = ['https://www.hamburg.de']
    start_urls = ['https://www.hamburg.de/branchenbuch/hamburg/10239785/n0/']
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8-sig'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        items = response.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'item')]")
        for item in items:
            business_name = item.xpath(".//h3[@class='h3rb']/text()").get()
            address1 = item.xpath(".//div[@class='address']/p[@class='extra post']/text()[1]").get()
            address2 = item.xpath(".//div[@class='address']/p[@class='extra post']/text()[2]").get()
            phone = item.xpath(".//div[@class='address']/span[@class='extra phone']/text()").get()

            yield {
                'Business Name': business_name,
                'Address1': address1,
                'Address2': address2,
                'Phone Number': phone
            }

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(HamburgSpider)
process.start()
```

Then run the code using `python HamburgSpider.py`. The code executes well in the powershell. But I don't know how to export to csv in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CrawlerProcess`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess) takes a settings object as a parameter.

Since scrapy 2.1, all options for feed exports can be set using the [`FEEDS`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std-setting-FEEDS) setting.
To get the result you want, something like this should be used:

```py
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'FEEDS': {
        'output.csv': {
            'format': 'csv',
            'encoding': 'utf-8-sig',
        }
    }
})
```

Another option is setting this in `custom_settings`, but I prefer using global options in most cases where it's possible (this also makes the `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING` setting unnecessary).